# php not inserting into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This issue I have had for several days now and I cannot seem to see where the issue is. I have looked at the functions in many ways, even looking up the php site but I can't solve this still. This is the code where I am having trouble:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($db_connect, "INSERT INTO forum_post(post_author, post_author_id, date_time, type, section_title, section_id, thread_title, post_body) VALUES($log_username, $log_id, now(), 'a', '$forum_section_title', '$forum_section_id', '$post_title', '$post_body')");
    $this_id = mysqli_insert_id($db_connect);
    header("location: ../view_thread.php?id=$this_id");
```

edited...

So I can show how I handled the error handling (rather so I can see the message):

```
$sql = mysqli_query($db_connect, "INSERT INTO forum_post(post_author, post_author_id, date_time, type, section_title, section_id, thread_title, post_body) VALUES('$log_username', '$log_id', now(), 'a', '$forum_section_title', '$forum_section_id', '$post_title', '$post_body')");
    if(mysqli_error($db_connect)) {
        $message = mysqli_error($db_connect);
        header("location: ../message.php?msg=$message");    
    }
    $this_id = mysqli_insert_id($db_connect);
    header("location: ../view_thread.php?id=$this_id");
    exit();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Using `mysqli_error($db_connect);` and commenting out the redirect seem the first things to do.

Comment: alway use  `$mysqli->error` for debugging as it would of probably guided you to the error. [link]http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php[link]

Comment: I am using mysqli_error now, let me check if I can figure this out

Comment: It appears to work fine for some reason because it did not give me an error...

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using PDO because it's safer and it's straight-forward. and because t just won't let you do mistakes and have problems.

Here is your code in PDO. Test this:

```
try {
    // Prepare our connection string
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, USER, PASS);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    // Connection error jumps here  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
// Prepare our Insert Query
$query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO forum_post(post_author, post_author_id, date_time, type, section_title, section_id, thread_title, post_body) VALUES(:post_author, :post_author_id, :date_time, :type, :section_title, :section_id, :thread_title, :post_body)");
// Get our data aligned in an array.
$data = array('post_author' => $log_username, 'post_author_id' => $log_id, 'date_time' => now(), 'type' => 'a', 'section_title' => $forum_section_title, 'section_id' => $forum_section_id, 'thread_title' => $post_title, 'post_body' => $post_body);
try {
    // Try to execute our Insert Query with the given Data
    $query->execute($data);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    // Insert error jumps here
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$this_id = $con->lastInsertId();
header("location: ../view_thread.php?id=$this_id");
```

Be sure to substitute your HOST, Database, User and Pass in the placeholders mentioned in the code...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you used `mysqli_error($db_connect);` because you should receive an error when you do.

One problem is that you are not quoting your string values:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($db_connect, "INSERT INTO forum_post(post_author, post_author_id, date_time, type, section_title, section_id, thread_title, post_body) 
         VALUES($log_username, $log_id, now(), 'a', '$forum_section_title', '$forum_section_id', '$post_title', '$post_body')");
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ here      ^^^^^ and here
//              (assuming $log_id is an integer...)
```

But I agree with @MiroMarkarian that you should use prepared statements (can be in mysqli as well).

Comment: You make a good point, I forgot those and for some reason the mysqli_error() did not catch it... I am trying to figure it out now

Comment: You were right about the the $log_id and the $log_username. I added the '' but it is not enough and I even added an "or die(mysqli_error($db_connect)); in the end but still does not give me any errors...

Comment: @EltonRodriguez Don't redirect while you are debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your php installation is set to report errors. Then die on unsuccessful MySQL query execution and inspect the error that you get.

To enable error reporting, put the following line at the top of your php file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```